# What does vbo.draw in webgl source code exactly do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

I have met a problem of webgl in chrome. In the webgl conformance test source code, I found a piece of code like below:

```
...
var vbo = new VBO(gl, {size:3, data:Quad.vertices});
vbo.draw(v);
...
```

I cannot find the function of vbo.draw in WebGL spec. Can anyone help me? I want to know what does this command do?

Thanks.

Comment: `VBO` is not part of WebGL. That's some JavaScript object/library used by whatever code you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

VBO refers to Vertex Buffer Object, and they are used to store data to be renders on a per vertex basis. The draw method is likely rendering the vertices to the current active surface using the currently configured rendering state.

Take a look here for more details on the VBO class: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/6197632e54bcd28dff3c3bf8e43d473687af19e6/conformance-suites/1.0.1/conformance/more/util.js

In particular, it's definition:

```
VBO = function(gl) {
  this.gl = gl;
  this.data = [];
  this.elementsVBO = null;
  for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i].elements)
      this.elements = arguments[i];
    else
      this.data.push(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes, it's JS, but I cannot find the library or other information.

Comment: No problem, I just update the answer with more details. All the best!

Comment: the author of that library has [a blog here](http://fhtr.blogspot.nl/) with contact info.